# Edge & Store have no internet access

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, microsoft-edge

I somehow must have scrambled my Win10 install: everythink is OK, Chrome works fine, but Edge keeps saying "Hmm, we can't reach this page". Also the Store does not seem to have internet access, and (the main issue for me) also Google Photo (which seems to rely on Edge).  Google Drive syncs fine, all other tools are OK.

I reinstalled Windows 10, running setup from Windows, with the hope it would recover from this without forcing me to reinstall every soft I have. The reinstalled seemed successfull, but did not improve that connectivity issue.

*Disclaimer*: I recently did some cleanup, and uninstalled SQL Server and Visual Studio and ran Ccleaner...and also uninstalled one or two of the numerous .Net frameworks and Visual C++ redistributable something (still have a dozen of those).

This is my last hope before reformatting and reinstalling from scratch.
As I said all works fine, except that Edge connectivity + the tools that seem to depend on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I don't know how and why, but in the `Network & Internet`, `Proxy`, `Use Setup Script` was ON. Turning this OFF restored everything to normal.

---

**Edit**: after some search, the culprit was [Lantern](https://getlantern.org/), that I had once installed, then removed, but which had left its proxy settings active in Edge

Comment: This did not work for me, so other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I also have the same symptoms, but Use Setup Script is Off, and has always been off as far as I know.